# Probability exponential distributuion problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Electronic store sells online two items, $A_1$, and $A_2$. Times between orders are independent variables with exponential distribution. In one hour there are $15$ orders of item $A_1$ on average, and item $A_2$ is only sold *with* order of item $A_1$ ( $A_2$ cannot be ordered without $A_1$). Probability of customer ordering $A_2$ is $50\%$. Items can be ordered from 8:00 to 22:00.

How many orders were placed in one day?

I'm totally stuck with this problem, and any hint or help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Edit your question to include some thought or effort. If not, it's only a matter of time before moderators place your question on hold

Answer (score 0):

The time between orders is [exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), therefore the orders are a [Poison process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process) with $\lambda = 15/$h.

How many orders are placed in one day?

The number of *orders* is equal to the number of orders of $A_1$ a [Poison distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) random variable with $\lambda=15\times 14$, call this X.

The number of *items ordered* is $X$ + $Y$, where $Y$ is the number of $A_2$ ordered, a random variable with a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $N=X$ and $p=0.5$

Answer (score 0):

It is really an R excercise - it is only a part of the more complex assignment.
I generate an vector of values(of unknown length, but since it is exponential distribution it is not very likely to exceed 60)
with rnorm(10000,15) and rbinom(10000,1,0.5) and with for loop I'll continually add to variable representing minutes in day ( hence 14*60=840) like this:

for (highNumber){

if(answer<840){
 answer=answer+nextGeneratedTime
}

else{
 return
}

}

Index of the vector where I stopped is number of first items sold per day.
Total number of items sold is the index where I stopped+number of one's from rbinom until that  index.